# Why is this regex a match?

Tags: c#, regex

Let me begin by stating that I am not the best at regex. I want to create a regex that verifies that something is a hexadecimal number, But the numbers are grouped per 2.

The regexes that I found online are good, but don't check for groupings of 2.

For example:

Good (length % 2 == 0):

- AF4C
- 5E8E6D
- 8C0F5C3E

Bad (length % 2 == 1):

- E5F
- D
- 4B2E4

The regexes that I tried: 
`var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^([0-9a-fA-f][0-9a-fA-f])+$");
regex.Match("3]").Success; //Why is this true?`

And
`var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^([0-9a-fA-f]{2})+$");
regex.Match("3]").Success; //Why is this true?`

Comment: `A-f` includes the character `]` (you probably wanted `A-F`)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Code Review is only for code that already works.

Comment: Thanks @Juhana .... DOH!!! Post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like user [Juhana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502381/juhana) answered in a comment, my problem was that I wrote `A-f` instead of 'A-F'. Quick fix, but drove me mad.